# Found nil value in dictionary when it isn't nil

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, option-type

I want to create `URL` from string in dictionary, but when I initialize it, the guard statement goes to `else` statement, because  `values["Image"]` is `nil`  and `return` the function. Here is a piece of my code

```
guard let imageURLInDatabase = URL(string: values["Image"]!) else { return }
let data = NSData(contentsOf: imageURLInDatabase)
```

I have create afew breakpoint in my code:

[image]

And here is my console log at this breakpoint:

[image]

What did I miss?

P.S
I tried to do it like:

`let imageURLInDatabase = URL(string: values["Image"]!)`

but I got error message `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value`

Edit 1:
I tried to do it like

```
    guard let imageString = values["Image"] else{return}
    guard let imageURLInDatabase = URL(string: imageString) else{
        return}
    let data = NSData(contentsOf: imageURLInDatabase)
```

And set breakpoints:
[image]

So `values["Image"]` can't be nil

Edit 2:

This is what is in `values["Image"]`:[image]

```
    some : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/blackjack-ef580.appspot.com/o/profiles_images%2FdwMGR8sKMvYauf6uQDtyop18cwy1.jpg?alt=media&token=5df48794-d3fd-4e5c-a72c-9928a8a43c4e\""
```

Comment: if your using Swift, you should be using Data, not NSData.

Comment: Is it any different?

Comment: `Data` is the Swift class. `NSData` is the Objective-C class.

Comment: But it is't big mistake to use NSDate?

Comment: @i_am_jorf no its just a part of url that I forgot to hide :)

Comment: You shouldn't be hiding _anything_. Hiding is the problem with the question; if you don't show the actual data, we're just guessing blind.

Comment: @rmaddy Why did you delete your answer?

Comment: The issue is nothing but the string is not valid for url. say values["image"] is "abcd" which is not a valid url string "protocol://otherpart" is a valid url. This might be the reason where your url object goes to guard else. your values["image"] is not nil here. Check and tell me.

Comment: i have edited my post can u look now?

Comment: Blast it, @K.Pilch, will you please paste _text_ into your question, not _pictures_ of text??? This is infuriating. Do you want help or not? If you provided the URL as _text_, testing it by passing it thru `URL(string:)` would be trivial. — Anyway, you've been given the right answer (twice).

Comment: I'm seeing a two quotation marks at the end of the URL in your second edit? Is a quotation mark in the string and is that valid for a URL?

Comment: @NerdyTherapist Correct. If that's real, it's the problem.

Comment: The problem is the extra quotation mark. Try this: `let s = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/blackjack-ef580.appspot.com/o/profiles_images%2FdwMGR8sKMvYauf6uQDtyop18cwy1.jpg?alt=media&token=5df48794-d3fd-4e5c-a72c-9928a8a43c4e\""; let url = URL(string:s)` You'll get `nil`.

Comment: Thanks guys for help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the extra quotation mark at the end of the URL string. Try this:

```
let s = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/blackjack-ef580.appspot.com/o/profiles_images%2FdwMGR8sKMvYauf6uQDtyop18cwy1.jpg?alt=media&token=5df48794-d3fd-4e5c-a72c-9928a8a43c4e\""
let url = URL(string:s)
```

You'll get `nil`.

Answer (score 3):

The problem isn't that `values["Image"]` is `nil`. The problem is that `values["Image"]` isn't a value URL string.

Make sure you properly encode spaces and other special characters in the URL.

And as a side note, do not use `NSData`, use `Data`.

Answer (score 0):

According to your trace, the problem isn't that `value["Image"]` is `nil`. If that were the case, you would have crashed rather than called `return`. Your problem is that whatever the value of `value["Image"]`, it is not a valid `URL`. Without seeing the value, it's difficult to know exactly what is wrong with it, but it is malformed in some way.

Answer (score -1):

This is because the dictionary `values` does not contains the key `Image`. So `values['Image']` will return nil, and force unwrapping a nil will crash the app.

Try using guard else statements to unwrap it

```
guard let imageValue = values["Image"] as? String else {
   //imageValue is nil here, handle accordingly
    return
}

guard let imageURLInDatabase = URL(string: imageValue) else {
  //imageURLInDatabase is nil here, handle accordingly
    return
}

let data = NSData(contentsOf: imageURLInDatabase)
```

**Edit 1:**

With your updated question, and the breakpoint image, values["Image"] is not null, imageURLInDatabase is nil due to which it goes to else case.

The reason could be that values["Image"] might not be returning a valid url, due to which URL(string: ..) fails.

**Edit 2 :**

Check the string url you just shared

```
"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/blackjack-ef580.appspot.com/o/profiles_images%2FdwMGR8sKMvYauf6uQDtyop18cwy1.jpg?alt=media&token=5df48794-d3fd-4e5c-a72c-9928a8a43c4e\""
```

has an extra quote in the end!

Comment: But he didn't say the app is crashing. He said it took the `else` path. He is _already_ using a `guard`. Read the question!

Comment: @K.Pilch The url has an extra quote in the end